# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with jar files

Tags: java, twitter, jar

Uploaded a jar file from my computer to a server and tried to run it. When I run it I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError and it seems to be related to the twitter4j jar that my main method depends on.

However, I have this jar file in my libraries so shouldn't this be included when I build my code in to a jar? Here's a pic in case it helps.

[image]

is the error that I'm getting. (can't upload a pic just yet.

Comment: What command did you enter to run the program?

Comment: @mthmulders java -jar /tmp/myapp.jar

Comment: When you get a NoClassDefFoundError, you need to look down the stack to see if there is another exception that caused the NCDFE.  In this case it's ClassNotFoundException on twitter4j.TwitterException.  This means that that class is entirely absent from the classpath or is improperly located in the classpath.  You need to figure out how to get the JAR containing that class into your classpath, in the proper location.

Comment: (Note that NCDFE has a dozen or so different causes -- this in only one case, and one of the easier ones to figure out.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what this has to do with twitter, but anyway, the issue is that you do not have the correct class files. In other words, when you are running your fat JAR in the command prompt, you do not have any libraries exported with it (Or if you do, you don't have that specific one).

Sometimes such an error can be because there is an incorrect version of java, however that is not the case here since java has got no "twitter" packages or classes in it.

Using something like JarSplice would fix this.

Comment: The jar file I'm using is called Twitter4J. There must be an easy way to include this jar with my own jar or something?

Comment: @user3504452 Look at JarSplice. That does exactly what you are asking. I have also heard that Maven is also an alternative, however I have never used it.

Comment: Using netbeans at the moment, will look at those but I would've thought there'd be a way to do this within netbeans.

Comment: I wouldn't call maven the alternative, its the de facto

Comment: @user3504452 Jarsplice will do the job irellevant of IDE. It is fiddly and annoying, but works. Because I have not got in the stage of my game where I am wanting to export a fat JAR more than once a month, then I have not bothered looking into alternatives.

Google around, there may be a solution somewhere. However, I do not believe it comes default with NetBeans.

I personally use Eclipse.

Comment: @redFIVE Just something i've heard.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you did not package the twitter4j classes inside your application jar, you need to tell Java where it can look for classes that are not inside your application jar. You typically use the classpath flag for that. In your case, it should look something like

```
java -cp /tmp/twitter4j.jar -jar /tmp/myapp.jar
```

An alternative would be to package all twitter4j's classes inside your application jar. This is called a 'fat' jar. How to make one depends on how you build your application jar.

Comment: So basically upload the twitter4j jar file on my server also? Not sure what that code actually does to be honest but I wonder if I just move my twitter jar to the same folder would it work

Comment: I personally think that my solution of creating a fat JAR is better for all situations and convenience. For example if he makes this a commercial game (Presuming stuff here), he won't want users to have to type that.

Answer (score 0):

The JAR file that you are trying to use needs to be in the classpath. This can be done by using the `-cp` attribute from the command line. However, when using `java -jar`, you cannot use the `-cp` attribute.

To get around this, you can do the following:

```
java -cp /tmp/myapp.jar;\path\to\external.jar com.example.package.MyClass
```

where MyClass has the `main()` method defined.

Alternately, you can specify jar files on the classpath using the manifest.mf file. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html for details.